# PHP - missing output from onClick output in an echo statement

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo"<div class='btn-likes'><input type='button' title='".ucwords($str_like)."' class='".$str_like."' onClick='addLikes(".$tutorial['id'].",".$str_like.")' /></div>";
```

**Output from above code is** :

```
<input title="Like" class="like" onclick="addLikes(51,like)" type="button">
```

**Output what I want is** :

```
<input title="Like" class="like" onclick="addLikes(51,'like')" type="button">
```

apostrophe is missing in `onclick="addLikes(51,'like')"`

I have try :

```
echo"<div class='btn-likes'><input type='button' title='".ucwords($str_like)."' class='".$str_like."' 
          onClick='addLikes(".$tutorial['id'].",'".$str_like."')' /></div>";
```

And the output is so viewy :

```
<input title="Like" class="like" onclick="addLikes(51," like')'="" type="button">
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
echo '<div class="btn-likes"><input type="button" 
    title="'.ucwords($str_like).'" class="'.$str_like.'" 
    onClick="addLikes('.$tutorial['id'].',\''.$str_like.'\')" /></div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Here how you can modify your code using some quotes escaping with `\`:

```
echo '<div class="btn-likes">
          <input type="button" title="' . ucwords($str_like) . '" class="' . $str_like . '" onClick="addLikes(' . $tutorial['id'] . ", '" . $str_like . "')\"/>
     </div>";
```